# How to get mpd tools for MPICH

Tags: linux, cluster-computing, fedora, mpich

I get a an error while installing MPICH, that the mpd files are missing.Can you please Suggest me with some links where i can get mpd tools for MPI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Hydra` it is a process management system for starting parallel jobs. Hydra is designed to natively work with multiple daemons such as ssh, rsh, pbs, slurm and sge.                 .

```
http://www.mpich.org/static/tarballs/3.0.2/hydra-3.0.2.tar.gz
```